# Jquery simple project

Tags: jquery

Here is a jquery simple project:

http://jsfiddle.net/Maizere/CnWqV/2/

I just wanted to know why the `hide()` method in the project works only for once .How to make it work everytime on mouseleave.Thank u .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDs must be **unique**.

If you want to have multiple elements, you need to use a classname.

---

Separately, you should remove the new elements after the hide animation finishes.
However, that won't help, in case the user moves the mouse back in before the animation finishes.

Comment: great thanks,i forgot that .Thank u again,this project disturbed my whole day